# ExtJS 4 I don't understand models + associations

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I don't think the documentation is very clear on this - at least I can't figure out how associations work with models in ExtJS 4. Lets look at a simple example:

**the models**

```
Ext.define('app.model.Goo', {
    ...
    fields: ['id', 'foo_id', 'goo_field'],
    belongsTo: 'Foo'
});

Ext.define('app.model.Foo', {
   ... 
   fields: ['id', 'foo_field'],
   hasMany: {model: 'Goo', name: 'goos'} //
});
```

this allows me to easily write a server response that returns nested data such as:

```
{ 
    success: true,
    foo: {
       id: 42
       foo_field: 'bacon',
       goos: [ 
           { id: 0, goo_field: 'velociraptor' }, 
           { id: 1, goo_field: 'spidermonkey' },
           ...
       ]
    }
}
```

and parse out the data into their respective models. But what if I want to load nested data *lazily*? Say I write my server such that it doesn't send any `goos` field in my returned `foo` object. What does it mean to write `foo.goos().load()`? What's being sent to my server then? `GET <proxy:url>/<'id' of foo>/goos` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to lazy load `goo` you should not send `goo` in the `foo` response. But instead you call foo.goos(). This wil return a `goo` **store** with a filtervalue `foo_id` on 42 (primary id from your `foo` instance). Basicly its doing something like this for you:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'app.model.Goo',
    filters: [
        {
            property: 'foo_id',
            value: 42
        }
    ]
});
```

So calling `load` does the request. Assuming you are using REST proxy, your `goo` proxy will do the following request: `GET <proxy:url>`with filter-queryparameters: `filter:[{"property":"foo_id","value":42}]`.

Also I believe you need to specify fully qualified class name (ie. `model: 'app.model.Goo'`).